# Push Token Invalidity

Tags: android, push, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

After the push function is integrated, the server interface returns error code 80300007 when a push message is sent to some users. For example, a Mate 30 client can obtain a token.

After the server sends a push request, the following information is returned:

```
response is {"_code": "80300007", "_msg": "All the tokens are invalid", "_requestId": "159496694237460153003301"}
```

In what situations will a user token become invalid? This is because the server knows this only when invoking a push request. Can the client determine that the token is invalid? What should the client do after the license expires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message receipt capability can be accessed. If invalid tokens are found based on the receipt, no push message is sent to the tokens.

> **What does result code 80300007 mean?**
> Description : The specified token is invalid.

**Troubleshooting**

1.Different apps on the same device need to use different tokens. However, the same token may be delivered.

2.The APK name and app ID configured for the app on the device are different from those applied from AppGallery Connect.

3.Check whether the URL for obtaining the authentication token is https://login.cloud.huawei.com/oauth2/v2/token.

4.Check whether the message sending URL is https://api.push.hicloud.com/pushsend.do when the HMS Core Push SDK 2.0 is integrated or whether it is [https://push-api.cloud.huawei.com/v1/[appId]/messages:send](https://push-api.cloud.huawei.com/v1/%5BappId%5D/messages:send) when the HMS Core Push SDK 3.0 or later is integrated.

For details, see:https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/push-receipt